# Change of entropy (Theromdynamics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I have two problems in connection with Change of entropy.

1.
How much is the entropy change of 1kg Helium (at 20 Celsius) if the pressure changes isotherm from 200*10^5 Pa to normal atmosphere pressure?

I have the answer in the book(M=4g/mol and delta S = 11kj / K) but unfortunately I do not know how should I work to get this solution. Help me, Please!

2. Under continuous pressure 5g Oxygen (27 Celsius and its V=104 cm^3) expand while its inner energy increasing by 836 J. How much heat (Q) is necessary for this progress? How much is the entropy change?

The book says the answer is: M= 32g/mol, Q=1170 J, delta S=2.82J/K

But how do I get these? Someone could explain it to me, please?

Comment: What are your thoughts on it so far?